# Django shop error: "No module named shop"

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-shop

When I'm launching a django shop I receive an error message: `ImportError: No module named shop`.

1. I've switched to my project dir;
2. activated `virtualenv`;
3. installed `django-shop`, using `pip install django-shop`;
4. added module `shop` to `settings.py` in my project directory;
5. added a string `(r'^shop/', include('shop.urls')),` in my `urls.py`.

All worked with no error. Any advises how to solve that problem?

Installed apps list from settings.py:

```
'INSTALLED_APPS = (
'djangocms_admin_style',
'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.messages',
'cms',
'menus',
'sekizai',
'treebeard',
'djangocms_style',
'djangocms_column',
'djangocms_file',
'djangocms_flash',
'djangocms_googlemap',
'djangocms_inherit',
'djangocms_link',
'djangocms_picture',
'djangocms_teaser',
'djangocms_video',
'reversion',
'shop',
'shop.addressmodel',
'eshop',
```

)'

Here is `pip freeze --local` results:

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
Django==1.7.10
django-classy-tags==0.6.2
django-cms==3.1.2
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.8.2
Django-Select2==4.3.1
django-treebeard==3.0
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.7
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.2.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.3
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.9
djangocms-link==1.6.2
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.6.0
djangocms-video==0.1
html5lib==0.999999
Pillow==2.9.0
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
tzlocal==1.2
wheel==0.24.0
```

Traceback from terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/stp/web/eshop/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/stp/web/eshop/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/stp/web/eshop/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/stp/web/eshop/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/stp/web/eshop/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named shop
```

Comment: add your INSTALLED_APPS here

Comment: Show `pip freeze --local`

Comment: Put all your traceback..Which line error occurs?

Comment: In your pip freeze, there is no `django-shop`.try reinstall it

Comment: reinstalled and worked fine :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pip freeze does not show django-shop installed. 
Are you sure it installed successfully?